# Download/Install Android App from Non-Market Web Server: How?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a test-download of my first app from a non-Market web server (mine).  I placed a signed APK on the server, browsed to it from my Nexus-S browser and clicked.  I get a brief message about downloading, but then zilcho, no install, no nothing.  And yes, I enabled "Unknown Sources" in the settings.  Each time I try this, a small red circle appears at the top-left of my screen with an incrementing number.

Should this work? Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I don't want to use ADB or an App installer program if avoidable (I want to let unsophisticated beta testers install it).

Thanks,
John

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to export the apk?

Comment: Yes. the Indigo release.

Comment: And so you DID press export, and didn't just copy the APK from the res folder?

It could be that your browser just isnt downloading it.

Comment: check that : there is no application with the same package name and different signature installed ; your phone is compatible with the api level specified in your manifest

Comment: Yes, correct.  I went thru the whole export process, including generating a keystore and all that.  I believe the  file *was* downloaded (from my server log). Should this have worked?

Comment: I deleted the already installed app, and re-tried - same result.

Comment: I believe API level is Ok - I use 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself (Duh), it was operator error.

The answer is that I didn't understand how download-install works.  After downloading APK, I had to go to "Downloads" on my phone and select the file to install.  It's all good now.

-John

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is done by the manufacturer. I've seen it on a few phones.
Try using a different ROM (like cyanogen) if you're rooted.

Comment: Making APK files unable to download through browser.
If you install Cyanogen ROM, your issue will be over.